# HttpWebRequest returns (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

The request gives the following error: 
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I cann't find a solution on internet. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json");
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            var parameters = string.Format("language={0}&latlng={1}&client={2}&signature={3}", "nl", "51.123456,5.612345", "gme-aa", "******_******=");

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            /*
             * Read HttpWeb Response
             */
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string Response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
```

EDIT:

I'm working inside Lowcode platform Outsystems. Outsystems creates the url inside WebRequest.Create() without the paramaters. So, I have access to webRequest object and need to pass the parameters.

Comment: Bad Request means the data you sent is not in the form required by the endpoint to service your request. It would be difficult to say without knowing what `parameters` evaluates to after formatting, and having a google api key to test with.

Comment: When I past the url + params to the browser (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=nl&latlng=51.123456,5.612345&client=gme-aa&signature=******_******=), then I get results. When I try to do inside the c# function, then I get the error

Comment: Yeah but the browser creates a GET request, and your code is creating a POST.

Comment: But I can not set the params with method GET without adding the params to WebRequest.Create()?

Comment: What's wrong with adding the parameters to `WebRequest.Create()`?

Comment: I'm working inside Lowcode platform Outsystems. Outsystems creates the url inside WebRequest.Create() without the paramaters. So, I have access to webRequest object and need to pass the parameters.

Comment: for clarity (I'm not familiar with Lowcode) do you not have `WebRequest.Create()` in your code? are you saying it is inside another method call that you have no access to?

Comment: Yes, it's inside a method that I can not access.

Comment: Why don't you not use LowCode? Or, if you have Set access to their WebRequest, just replace the reference with your own. I am not impressed with LowCode (whatever that is) if it restricts you in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HTTP **"GET"** Method.

In a GET request, you pass parameters as part of the query string.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=fr&latlng=51.123456,5.612345&key={apiKey}");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "GET";

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I'm working inside Lowcode platform Outsystems. Outsystems creates the url inside WebRequest.Create() without the paramaters. So, I have access to webRequest object and need to pass the parameters.

Comment: Can you try my code above changing HttpWebClient to WebClient ? WebRequest.Create($"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=fr&latlng=51.123456,5.612345&key={apiKey}");

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start), the API is expecting a POST method and receiving the parameters in the URL and not the body.

If you are using the OutSystems platform you can use the Consume REST API functionality to easily call the web service without using code. Configure your API like this (you can copy the example JSON from the documentation page above):

[image]